# Improve Execution Time of MATLAB Function

Tags: matlab, time, execution

The following function calculates the Gaussian Kernel and is part of the Kernel Ridge Regression algorithm that I wrote. I was wondering how could I modify this function properly in order to improve the execution time (i.e. get rid of the two for loops). Any ideas?

```
function [K] = calculate_krr_gaussiankernel(Xi,Xj,S)
    K = zeros(size(Xi,1),size(Xj,1));
    for Ixi = 1:size(Xi,1),
        for Ixj = 1:size(Xj,1),
            K(Ixi,Ixj) = exp((-norm(Xi(Ixi,:) - Xj(Ixj,:)) .^ 2) ./ (2 * (S .^ 2)));
        end
    end
end
```

EDIT: The formula:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version that's most likely faster. It might however give rise to memory issues for large `Xi`/`Xj`.

```
function K = calculate_krr_gaussiankernel(Xi, Xj, S)

  %# create an array of difference between Xi(r,:) and Xj(s,:) for all r,s
  delta = bsxfun(@minus, permute(Xi,[1 3 2]), permute(Xj,[3 1 2]));

  %# calculate the squared norm
  ssq = sum(delta.^2, 3);

  %# calculate the kernel
  K = exp(-ssq./(2*S.^2));
```

Here's an explanation of what I'm doing:

- the bsxfun line: I reshape the inputs, such that I can get, at every (i,j), the difference vector in the third dimension
- the ssq line simply takes the sum of squares. I could take the square root here and thus get the norm, but since we'll square that again, anyway, there's no point in that.
- the final line implements the formula in the OP, where `ssq` is the squared norm of the differences.

Comment: @eualin: I have added an explanation of the individual steps.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly double the speed (approximately) since K is symmetric.  In addition you can calculate the `norm` of the difference vector and then make a single call to `exp()` which may be faster than calling `exp()` over and over again.  Putting this together:

```
function [K] = calculate_krr_gaussiankernel(Xi,Xj,S)
    arg = zeros(size(Xi,1),size(Xj,1));
    for Ixi = 1:size(Xi,1),
        % diagonal elements can be done in outer loop:
        arg(Ixi,Ixi) = norm(Xi(Ixi,:) - Xj(Ixi,:));
        for Ixj = Ixi+1:size(Xj,1), % off-diagonals done once and copied
            arg(Ixi,Ixj) = norm(Xi(Ixi,:) - Xj(Ixj,:));
            arg(Ixj,Ixi) = arg(Ixi,Ixj);
        end
    end
end

K = exp(( -arg.^ 2) ./ (2 * (S .^ 2)))
```